# vba to save excel file with given name to specific location

Tags: excel, vba, filenames, excel-2016, savefiledialog

I recently asked about saving an excel file with a specific name to a set location:
[Getting correct default save name and save directory with spaces in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043848/getting-correct-default-save-name-and-save-directory-with-spaces-in-vba/)

I want to use this same procedure but in a somewhat different way. I tried to edit the code to make it work, but I keep on have a black filename screen when I execute the code.

The file I want to save with the routine is a template which is being refreshed with new data every 4 weeks. It is a read-only file which functions as a source template and after updating the data, I has to be saved on a different location to keep the original source file save from errors/unwanted modification.

When refreshing, the template opens a file which contains the refresh script named "refresh_segment_template.xlsm".

the code in the *template* is:

```
Option Explicit

Dim aantalrijen As Long

Const SheetSchaduwblad As String = "schaduwblad"
-------
Sub vernieuwalles()
Dim myTemplate As String: myTemplate = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Dim myTool As String: myTool = "refresh_segment_template.xlsm"

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Workbooks.Open GetPath & myTool
  Application.Run myTool & "!vernieuwalles", myTemplate

  Call Windows(myTool).Close(False)

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Private Function GetPath() As String
Dim myPosition As Integer
Dim myPath As String: myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  myPosition = InStr(StrReverse(myPath), "\") - 1
  myPosition = Len(myPath) - myPosition

  GetPath = Mid(myPath, 1, myPosition - 1) & "\XLAM\"

End Function
```

the code in the *refresh_segment_template* is:

```
Option Explicit

Dim aantalrijen As Long

Const SheetSchaduwblad As String = "schaduwblad"
------------------    
Sub vernieuwalles(mytemplate As String)

  Windows(mytemplate).Activate

  On Error GoTo Err_

  Application.StatusBar = "Bezig met vernieuwen"

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'  Call SheetOpschonen

  Call datawissen
  Call dataplaatsen
  Call kolomtitels
  Call toevoegen
  Call maaktabel
  Call refreshpivots

Exit_:
  Application.StatusBar = ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Exit Sub

Err_:
  Call MsgBox(Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
  Resume Exit_

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
    -------------
    Sub refreshpivots()
    Dim workbook_Name As Variant
    Dim location As String
    Dim filename As String

    filename = "M:\Commercie\Marktdata\IRi\Segment Ontwikkeling\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name

      ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    workbook_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel binary sheet (*.xlsb), *.xlsb", InitialFileName:="M:\Commercie\Marktdata\IRi\Segment Ontwikkeling\")

    If workbook_Name <> False Then

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=filename, WriteResPassword:="TM", FileFormat:=50

    End If

    End Sub
```

I am now wondering how I can make the last script to use the filename of the *template* and save it on the give location in the script (i.e. M:\Commercie\Marktdata\IRi\Segment Ontwikkeling).

When I execute the code above, I get a 'save as' screen, but with no filename given, only the set directory is correct.

The *refresh_segment_template* is a *.xlsm* file. The template is a *.xlsb* file.

Comment: Backslashes are generally used as escape characters (which mean they give another meaning to the succeeding character). Can you replace every single backslash by a double one? (`M:\\Commercie\\Markdata\\...`)

Comment: getting the location works fine, however getting the right filename is not working. In the case of the mentioned question, I have troubles because of the file type and the desired name (xlsm vs xlsb). Because this template *(.xlsb)* uses a separate update script *(xlsm)* in I am wondering if this update script interferes with the save as script and causes a file extension conflict.

Comment: @Dominique, backslashes are escape characters in C and some other languages, not in VB.